# How to call a method from another class without creating an object

Tags: c#

How can I call method whithout creating class.

Example

```
public class1 {
    class2 = new class2();
    int size;
    private void method() {
        size = class2.size;
    }
}

public class2 {
    private void method() {
        //call method from class1
    }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the answer from @Matt, you could use the [static modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static). Please note that when a method is `static` it cannot access non-static fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that making the `method` of `class1` *static* (add the `static` reserved word before private)

That way you can call the method as `class1.method();`

Hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: `internal static void method() {...}` - we have to change the method into `internal` or `public`

Comment: Thats correct, of course he has to change the accesibility of the method too in order to use it from another class. Could have added that.

Answer (score 0):

I mean it:

```
public Class1 {
    Class2 class2 = new Class2();
    public int size;
    public Class1() {
        class2.handler += method1;
    }
    private void method1() {
        size = class2.size;
    }
}

public Class2 {
    ...
    public int size;
    public delegate void Handler();
    public Handler handler;
    private void method2() {
        size = UpdateSize();
        handler?.Invoke();
    }
    private int UpdateSize() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to your question.  If this is meant to make your question clearer, then _edit_ your question and add this code to it.  Then delete this answer.